# Can you deprecate an attribute in Rust?

Tags: rust, attributes, deprecated, deprecation-warning, rust-proc-macros

Say I have this macro definition:

```rust
#[proc_macro_derive(Builder, attributes(builder, group, groups))]
#[proc_macro_error]
pub fn derive_builder(input: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
    // -- snip --
}
```

And I want to deprecate `group`, and have users use `groups` instead. You can't simply do:

```rust
#[proc_macro_derive(Builder, attributes(builder, #[deprecated] group, groups))]
```

And throwing warnings is currently only [available on nightly](https://docs.rs/proc-macro-error/latest/proc_macro_error/macro.emit_warning.html)

How do I tell users to phase out the use of `group`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like with `compile_error!()`, expand to a call to a deprecated function. Probably, the best way is to have a deprecated exported function from your macro's support lib:

```rust
#[deprecated = "the `group` attribute is deprecated. Use `groups` instead"]
#[doc(hidden)]
pub const fn group() {}
```

And expand to something like:

```rust
const _: () = ::my_crate::group();
```

Of course, make sure to set the correct span so the error points to the right location.

Comment: That is actually really smart! Thank you